# LC balun in ADS

Tags: ads, balun

I'm studying  LC balun with bluenrg-1 now, and trying to calculator values in ADS simulation. But I find that the recommend circuit about this part in datasheet is different with what I have searched on net, such as a parallel capacitor has been set between differential pair and single-ended 50 Ω, and also, a capacitor has been series in balun's inductor to ground. I don't know why do like this, and calculate them with no idea. I'd like an explanation.

[bluenrg-1 datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/bluenrg-1.pdf)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please write to the best of your ability. This includes starting each sentence with capital letter and running your text via a spellcheck.

Comment: And I also want to know that whether we need consider about the differential pair's return loss in balun. Because I see people simulated balun in ADS never mention it (input:S11,S22), but rather single-end S33...